# Unable to install Windows 2012 R2 on Raid 1

Tags: installation, windows-server-2012-r2, raid-1, hp-proliant

I have a problem installing Windows Server R2 on a HP ProLiant 360e Gen8.
There is a Raid 1 with 2 600GB SATA disks configured inside the b120i Smart Array Controller.

First time i fired up the setup via booting on a USB 2 installation medium it didn't show the logical drive. After searching some time i found out that i have to enable Virtual Disk Image.

The drive now shows up in the Windows installation setup but i'm still unable to choose the partition. It shows this message:

> "We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For
>   more information, see the Setup log files."

The solutions suggested on other sites didn't help:

- Changing boot order so that the target disk is the first Formating
- Partition and transforming to GPT via DISKPART

The log file says:

```
> DiskRegionSupportsCapability:Disk [2] is BLOCKED against capability
> [CanBeSystemVolume] for the following reasons... LogReason: [BLOCKING
> reason for disk2: CanBeSystemVolume] The selected disk is not the
> computer's boot disk. CanBeSystemVoume: Volume at disk [1] offset
> [0x7e00] doesn't meet criteria for system volumes...
> DiskRegionSupportsCapability:Disk [1] is BLOCKED against capability
> [CanBeSystemVolume] for the following reasons... LogReasons: [BLOCKING
> reason for disk 1: CanBeSystemVolume] Setup does not support
> configuration of or installation to disks connected through a USB or
> IEEE 1394 port. Remedy was applied for said disk rule
```

Comment: Since your dealing with GPT, that means you must boot while in UEFI mode, is that the case?

Comment: Is there a driver you need to provide Windows setup for the RAID controller?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried with GPT too, meaning without it didn't work either, i'll try UEFI when i'm at home.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator As far as i know those driver are located inside the Virtual Disk Image, before the logical drive did not even show up.

Comment: @F.H. The driver would be for the controller, not the VD. You would get them from HP's website.

Comment: What do you mean you "tried with GPT too".  I already know you tried that, but you were in the wrong mode, unless you enabled UEFI only mode.

Comment: What i was trying to say is, i tried it with MBR too and had the same result. Anyway the server does not support UEFI, i think support started on Gen9 rather than Gen8. I still had no luck so far and will try a different USB-stick now.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator what do you mean with VD? Virtual Disk? Where would i install this driver?

Comment: VD= virtual disk. You would provide the driver to the Windows setup program during installation. You should see an option to install a driver when selecting the disk to install Windows on.

Comment: I found this driver but it is an exe-file and not meant for installation during setup. Do you know where i can find this driver?

Comment: You can get the drivers from HP's website.

Comment: I dont find your mentioned drivers. But i don't think that this is the issue because it never asks for missing drivers. I now tried installing it via intelligent provisioning with an ISO file but it shows the message "Window cannot find the Microsoft Software License Terms. Make sure the installation sources are valid and restart the installation." during installation. My guess is that the installation media is corrupt. Should i use NTFS or FAT32? The server does not support UEFI.